# How to install Ubuntu without losing data?

Tags: installation, 13.04

Currently I have ubuntu 13.04 64bit installed on my 320gb partition. All of my work, music and videos are stored in the video and music folders. Is there any way to reinstall Ubuntu 13.04 again without losing my data?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? And is there a problem with back-upping your data(Music, Videos) to the spare partition, format the current one and install Ubuntu fresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert the Ubuntu 13.04 installation disc and select `install`, it will ask you if you want to keep the files in you Home folder (videos, music etc). This way you can reinstall Ubuntu without losing your data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you reinstall Ubuntu over itself by default unless you explicitly select to format your partitions Ubuntu will keep your data.